How can I retrieve more than 100 assets using CreateEntityScroller in Sitecore Content Hub?
I'm using the following code to retrieve assets with CreateEntityScroller in Sitecore Content Hub:
var result = MClient.Querying.CreateEntityScroller(query, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
await result.MoveNextAsync();

Currently, I'm only able to get the first 50 assets with this approach. I need to retrieve more than 100 assets and possibly even more if necessary.
I tried using queryAsync(), which allows me to retrieve all assets at once, but it seems limited to 10,000 assets.
Is there a way to use CreateEntityScroller to fetch more than 100 assets (and ideally remove the cap at 50 per page)? Alternatively, is there another method to bypass the 10,000 asset limit?
Any advice on how to work around these limitations would be appreciated!

i can take more than 100 assets by adding take with query
